# Page Navigation Within a Post with Specific post_type defined not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, pagination, custom-post-type

http://lakers.sonikastudios.com/gallery/sample-gallery-post-1/

That post has several pages using the  quicktag of Wordpress. This post is also is a custom post_type.. using the following code in the functions.php in the theme template.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
    function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'gallery',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Galleries' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Gallery' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'comments')
            )
        );
```

With this code, I managed to get a custom post type appearing in the admin section just fine. I added a new article there, with the page flippers..

So using the wp_link_pages() function, I got the page flipping functions working. But it only works on regular posts under the categories, but not for the posts that are defined as the 'gallery' post_type. For example, this page http://lakers.sonikastudios.com/editorials/catching-the-buss-to-the-hall-of-fame/3/ works just fine with the pagination within the post.

I'm not using any plugins that affect the post display method or navigation, and I did not mess with the .htaccess file - whatever Wordpress wrote is what I got there.

Any help would be great.. the site's almost ready and we hit this bottleneck and it's killing me!

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress, and I started development with the Whiteboard theme (the new one made for WP3). ]

UPDATED:
gallery.php (assigned via the Page module to display the post_type "gallery" - I confirmed that this is the file that loads when I load a gallery post_type post)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery
*/
?>

<?php get_header();

$exclude = array();

?>
<div class="grid_11" id="mainbar">



    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $exclude[]=get_the_ID();
    ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('grid_11 alpha omega'); ?>>
                <h2><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? the_title();?>"><? the_title();?></a></h2>
                <div class="social_media_balloons">
                <?
                if (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual();
                ?>
                <?
                if (function_exists('tweetmeme')) echo tweetmeme();
                ?>
                </div>
                    <?
                    $author_gravatar = get_gravatar(get_the_author_meta('user_email'));
                    ?>
                    <img src="<? echo $author_gravatar;?>" class="alignleft" />
            <?
            echo posted_by_and_category();

            ?>

                    <div class="grid_11 alpha omega">

                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <div id="single_article_selectors">

                        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="single_article_selector">&after=</div>'); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="single_article_selector">&after=</div>&next_or_number=next'); ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="grid_11 alpha omega" id="social_media_links">
                        <div class="grid_5 alpha">
                            <p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/LakersNation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/twittericon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Follow Lakers Nation </a></p>
                            <p><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LakersNation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/rssicon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Subscribe to Lakers Nation</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_5 omega">
                            <p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/lakersnation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/fbicon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" class="alignleft">Become a Fan on Facebook</a></p>
                            <p><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-of-l-nation/id349346678?mt=8" target="_blank"><img src="/images/iphoneicon.png" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Download our Free iPhone App</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                        <div class="shadow_divider"></div>
                    </div><!--#post-content-->

                    <!-- If a user fills out their bio info, it's included here -->
                    <div id="post-author" class="grid_11 alpha omega">
                        <h3>Written by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></h3>
                        <div id="author-gravatar">
                            <!-- This avatar is the user's gravatar (http://gravatar.com) based on their administrative email address -->
                            <?php echo get_avatar( $curauth->user_email, $default = '<path_to_url>' ); ?>
                        </div><!--#author-gravatar -->
                        <div id="authorDescription">
                            <?php the_author_meta('description') ?> 
                            <div id="author-link">
                                <p>View all posts by: <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></p>

                            </div><!--#author-link-->
                        </div><!--#author-description -->
                    </div><!--#post-author-->

                </div><!-- #post-## -->

                <div class="grid_11 alpha omega next_prev_links">
                    <div class="grid_3 alpha">
                        <p>
                            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div><!--.older-->
                    <div class="grid_3 omega" style="float:right; text-align:right;">
                        <p>
                            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &raquo;') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div><!--.older-->
                </div><!--.newer-older-->

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?><!--end loop-->
</div><!--#content-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single.php (regular post display template by default..)

```
<?php get_header();

$dirpath = str_replace(get_bloginfo('url'), '',get_bloginfo('template_directory'));
?>
<div class="grid_11" id="mainbar">



    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $exclude[]=get_the_ID();
    ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('grid_11 alpha omega'); ?>>

            <?
            echo posted_by_single();
            ?>
            <div class="grid_11 alpha omega">
                <div id="single_post_title">
                <h1><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? the_title();?>"><? the_title();?></a></h1>

                </div>
                <div class="social_media_balloons">
                <?
                if (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual();
                ?>
                <?
                if (function_exists('tweetmeme')) echo tweetmeme();
                ?>
                </div>

                <div class="grid_11 alpha omega">

                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <div id="single_article_selectors">

                    <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="single_article_selector">&after=</div>'); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="single_article_selector">&after=</div>&next_or_number=next'); ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="grid_11 alpha omega" id="social_media_links">
                        <div class="grid_5 alpha">
                            <p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/LakersNation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/twittericon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Follow Lakers Nation </a></p>
                            <p><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LakersNation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/rssicon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Subscribe to Lakers Nation</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_5 omega">
                            <p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/lakersnation" target="_blank"><img src="/images/fbicon.jpg" alt="Twitter" width="32" class="alignleft">Become a Fan on Facebook</a></p>
                            <p><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-of-l-nation/id349346678?mt=8" target="_blank"><img src="/images/iphoneicon.png" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32" class="alignleft">Download our Free iPhone App</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="shadow_divider"></div>
                </div><!--#post-content-->


            </div><!-- #post-## -->



                <div class="grid_11 alpha omega next_prev_links">
                    <div class="grid_3 alpha">
                        <p>
                            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Previous post') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div><!--.older-->
                    <div class="grid_3 omega" style="float:right; text-align:right;">
                        <p>
                            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &raquo;') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div><!--.older-->
                </div><!--.newer-older-->
            <div class="grid_11 alpha omega" id="comments_container">
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?><!--end loop-->
</div><!--#mainbar-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Nobody has this answer? I tried the WP forum, Google, and Stack Overflow. There must be somebody out there!

Comment: Why don't you try posting this at [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).  One of the new StackExchange beta sites.

Comment: can you post the template your using for single custom post types?  Is it the same as single.php used for regular posts?

Comment: Added. I didn't even know there was a WP answers site. I might do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue your having is pagination with custom post type.   There is a [good thread on WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-listing?replies=27) with some examples and solutions used to get it working.

A similar question has been answered already on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408433/how-to-paginate-results-with-custom-post-types-on-wp)

---

**Edit:**

#### I was not able to reproduce the error using the code you provided.

See: [Custom Post Type Pagination Test](http://press-themes.com/wordpress/gallery/test-gallery-1/)

To create the test I took the following steps:

1. Uploaded and installed the Whiteboard theme from the themes home page
2. Added the sample code provided to functions.php to create the post type
3. Copied the code provided "Gallery Template" and renamed it single-gallery.php

(Template hierarchy looks for single-PostType.php then single.php when displaying a single post type page)

4. Created a new gallery by clicking gallery add new
5. Inserted 4 images using add media
6. Inserted `<!--nextpage-->` between each image
7. Saved post and updated permalinks

[image]

Test Environment

- WordPress version: 3.0.1
- PHP version: 5.2.13
- Theme: whiteboard
- Permalink: /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

Comment: Thank you - however your Wordpress thread has to do with pagination of the many posts, not pagination within a post that is divided by the <!--nextpage--> quicktag. Totally different issue from mine.

Comment: so. the tutorial I found was botched in its process. The proper way to channel to the template file was to simply use the single-gallery.php file name, rather than setting up a page and linking the template etc.