# Why my wordpress single custom post navigation is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

first of all, I'm a total noob to WordPress, but this current project am working on requires wordpress, so duty call I had to do it.

I have created 4 categories and each category gets listed on different pages.
The categories are :

1- Article 2- Video 3- Slideshow 4-Audio

This is how I list each category on it's own page :
This is for READ cat.

```
<?php

            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query('cat=8&showposts=6'.'order=DESC'.'cat=10'
.'orderby=post_date'.'offset=0'.'&paged='.$paged);



            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?> 

            <td class="leftBoxes ">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#blog">   
            <div class="imgMargin"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div></a>
           <br>

            <div class="boxScrollsBlogsView readFet">
                 <a  href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?>#blog" >
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
            <P class="pal"> 
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            </P>
            </a>
            </div>

            </td>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I use this snippet to redirect each category to it's own Single page in the single.php

```
 <?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category('read') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/singlePages/singleReadBlog.php');
}
elseif ( in_category('view') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/singlePages/singleViewBlog.php');
}
elseif ( in_category('listen') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/singlePages/singleListenBlog.php');
}
elseif ( in_category('watch') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/singlePages/singleWatchBlog.php');
}

?>
```

now this all works fine, but on the single post page the NEXT Post, Previous Post Goes to other categories as well, it doesn't stop at Only Video or Sildeshow or a specific category.

now I red some suggestions saying that I did this all wrong and should have registered it as a function.

can anyone give a suggestion ?

These questions suggest solutions for the Navigation of the listing but that works fine for me, the single post navigation is somehow messed up for me :

[Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732155/page-navigation-within-a-post-with-specific-post-type-defined-not-working-in-wor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may know that you don't have to create pages to list a category content ?

Anyway, concerning your template if/elseif, you could have done it using the single_template filter :

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     if ( in_category('read') ) {
         $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
      }
 }
 return $single_template;
}

add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_post_type_template" ) ;
```

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template

For your prev/next posts, check the previous_post_link function that lets you restrict them to the same category as the currently displayed post :

```
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', TRUE);
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link

Comment: you are man of the hour! SAVED ma back! Thanks, to be honest this is first time using WP, and I didn't know the filtering thing... I usually work on Rails and Django