# Page break not working for WordPress custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to break single WordPress post into multiple pages and i know that i can simply achieve this using  **wp_link_pages** function but unfortunately it's not working for my custom post types. For custom post types it's generating the links but when i click on the link nothing happen.

I have tried to find out the issue but did not got any clue. Is i have to do anything extra for my custom post types to use **wp_link_pages** function?

Comment: Look for this answer, it is the same question  
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732155/page-navigation-within-a-post-with-specific-post-type-defined-not-working-in-wor

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following single code in the position you'd like your content
split.ensure that you are writing the code in the "Text" display editor
rather than the default "Visual display editor(note the two tabs displayed towards the top right in the editor)

```html
<!--nextpage-->
```

top right of your post or page editing screen)".